# roslaunch multiple turtlebots

Tags: ros, roslaunch, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, has anyone successfully run roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal launch for multiple turtlebots (3 to be exactly) while using the concept of one ROS MASTER and the other robots point to the address of the Master.

if so, please guide me as i am having trouble with this. how to run bringup commands in this network would be great.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215084/roslaunch-multiple-turtlebots/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2015-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my experience it is difficult (impossible?) to create launch files to run multiple Turtlebots within one ROS instance.  I suggest that you check out rocon:

http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_concert/Tutorials/indigo/Concert%20Bringup

I haven't used it, but it is intended to solve this problem.

---

Originally posted by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) with karma: 228 on 2015-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-08-04**:
nsprague, I am checking it out right now.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2015-08-11**:
nsprague, there is a network system call multimaster_fkie and it seem to be the easiest right now. I'll update once i have implented it fully. thanks

**Comment by [marlon](https://answers.ros.org/users/29306/marlon/) on 2017-02-09**:
Any progress made here?

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2017-02-09**:
I do not have much progress with the guide. I kept having issues with bringup during the process.